# Should I upload my big C-language project to Github in hope of it helping me get a job in the future?

Tags: job

Recently I have finished my big project, which is basically PDP8 Computer simulation made in C.

I was thinking about uploading it to Github because I hope it may help me get a job in future after I show my big projects to the owner of a company I am trying to work for.

Considering I am at the first year of Computer Science and IT university, do you think I should upload these kinds of projects on Github?
Will it help me get a job in case I want to show my past work to the boss hiring me?

Comment: This really isn't a question for Academia since your goals are job related. But there is no real rush to decide this, given you are in the first year. Your profile says you are "awful at coding". If true, think again about this.

Comment: This site is for people working in academia. You seem to be concerned about getting a job in industry ("the owner of a company"), which would make this question inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @Buffy Eh i am just exaggerating in biography.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Good luck in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's solid work, you're proud of it, and you don't mind sharing it with the world, then sure!  Having examples of past code to point at is always helpful, especially when you're very early in your career and have little else to distinguish yourself with.  It's even better if you think that someone else might find use in the thing.

That is... assuming that it's a personal project, or otherwise somehow unique to you.  If the "big project" you're referring to is effectively homework for a class, and everyone else in class is *also* producing a PDP8 Computer simulation in C, then it's a lot less interesting.

Additionally, it's probably a good idea to keep adding projects to your account as you go.  Being able to show progression to your potential employers when you go for your interview is great.  Having the only example of your code be the thing that you bodged together as a freshman is not so great.

...and for the next project, you could even start out with the thing on github, and use it as the source control tool it's meant to be.  There's a number of kids out there your age who don't really understand about source control, and having a low-key way of indicating that you're not one of those, without making a *thing* about it is all upside and no downside.

Comment: Thank you for the given opinion, means a lot!

Comment: Hmmm, there are a lot of people of _any_ age that don't understand source control.

Answer (score 0):

It can basically never hurt you by making your code public on github.

The thing is most repositories are never used. If you want your code to get attention you need to write papers about it and give talks about your code. There are literally hundreds of millions of repositories, and a search of any keyword will give thousands of results. Typically, for any well known problem/use case, there are already several prominent repositories, in addition to the many hundreds of repositories that receive essentially 0 attention.

If you want your code to stand out, it needs to do something that none of the existing repositories can do. This is a nontrivial task. Probably the easiest example of something that would "stand out" would be to implement a method in a well known paper, when there are currently no public implementations of that paper's method.

So in short: it won't hurt you to post your code, but it also probably won't help you unless your code can do something notable and unique.

Comment: If you advertise in your resume having a few repos at GitHub I can assure you someone on a hiring team will have a very critical look. I'd be sure it's good quality stuff, done well, and shows a bit of maturity. One hears people  refer to "grad student code"; it's not a compliment and doesn't seem to help ones case. Applicants can be plenty and the competition cutthroat.

Comment: @Taw Thanks for the opinion, means a lot!